# Atomic vs NonAtomic when to use in Objective-C iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, thread-safety, properties, atomic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C properties: atomic vs nonatomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic)

IN regards to he **@property** directives and setting the attribute **nonatomic** versus **atomic**:

I do understand that you get a performance boost using the nonatomic attribute because the system does not lock the class variable to prevent from complications due to threading. Most examples and code I see in fact do use nonatomic most of the time. I think this is due to the fact that apps generally run on the main thread and don't use threads in their code.  But, I would suspect that a lot of the objects and their methods under the hood are thread based and may need to be locked down if i want to retain and access them. Is this true? and if so, how would i know to lock down that object by using the @property(assign, retain) .

In other words, in what case would one find the case to use **@property(assign, retain)** when **not** writing threads in my app?

Comment: assign and retain?  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C properties: atomic vs nonatomic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic) and note that `atomic` does **not** guarantee thread-safety